# nginx can't load css, js from webpack output

Tags: node.js, nginx, webpack, vue.js

i use vue js [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) for development, when dev run smoothly, but unfortunately after npm run build (run in nginx) nginx can't load, look this:

```
x GET http://localhost/static/css/app.335db141d4c13fd545c8362771dbe30a.css 
x GET http://localhost/static/js/manifest.a8a366914bb58ec98264.js 
x GET http://localhost/static/js/vendor.538766e755f95e4f1561.js 
x GET http://localhost/static/js/app.23582232aa46a8daf39d.js 
x GET http://localhost/static/js/manifest.a8a366914bb58ec98264.js 
x GET http://localhost/static/js/vendor.538766e755f95e4f1561.js 
x GET http://localhost/static/js/app.23582232aa46a8daf39d.js
```

this nginx conf:

```
 user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

this default conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html 
    {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}
    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

this error display 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zk0H.png)

please give me solution , or ask for more detile

Comment: please post default.conf file, and full error text from error log.

Comment: default.conf and error display added , when npm run build no error

Comment: is your project name static or something else? configuring nginx for local does give me goosebump though.

Comment: yes, this files name : 
manifest.23fa48f97412a4e9a062.js ,
app.47b25068d9f42f3f6fe2.js , 
vendor.538766e755f95e4f1561.js, manifest.23fa48f97412a4e9a062.js.map

Comment: if i click link in view-source by browser show error code 404

Comment: is your `/static` folder inside `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Comment: yes it is there

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your nginx.conf:

sendfile off;